# How to pronounce "nₒ" properly

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics

People here (Hong Kong) like to pronounce *n<sub>0</sub>* ("n subscript zero") as "N-nor"; "N-zero" seems to be acceptable. I am wondering what's the most popular pronunciation in English.
I am actually a little confused by "N-nor". Where does it come from? Is it understood in America or England?

Comment: I've never heard of *"N-nor".* Could it be *"N-nought",* pronounced in a Hong Kong accent? I have no idea what a Hong Kong accent is like, but *"N-nought"* (which would sound just like *"N-nort"* in many British accents) is a common term for *N* subscript 0.

Comment: I think I've usually heard "n sub zero" for this (saying the "sub" makes it clear we're talking about a subscript and not an exponent).

Comment: Could you provide an alternate representation or description for those of us who see "n[little box with the numbers 20 and 92]"?

Comment: @Martha Do you see it correctly, in the question body?

Comment: @Kiamlaluno, yes, thank you. Unfortunately, I don't think that fix will work for the question title. :/ Not sure what (if anything) to do about that.

Comment: I am not sure HTML tags are allowed in the title, or if they are rendered.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: why did you change 'sub' to 'subscript'? The OP was stating his pronunciation, not giving some description. If you want to give a description of the thing (that is, not typeset) then give it separately.

Comment: @Mitch See the previous comments; what you are referring to has been added from me because not all users were able to see the letter _nₒ_ in the title; it's me who added "n sub zero," and then changed it to "n subscript zero," always to avoid issues with who was not seeing the letter described by the OP. Actually, it's me who added `n<sub>0</sub>`in the text of the question too.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I guess it's either because of the accent or my ignorance of the "t" at the end. "t" is not pronounced anyway.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: oops, sorry, I didn't see that you had originated that, the quotes threw me since all the other pronunciations were quoted.

Comment: @LLS: you say that people in Hong Kong pronounce it "n nor". Is that how you pronounce it? If not what is your dialect of English? ("n nor" is totally new to me, an AmE speaker, I say "n zero" or "n sub zero".)

Comment: @Mitch: I didn't read it that way. If I really need to read it out, I would read "n zero". From the answers I think it should be "n-nought". But I am not sure whether it's because people here don't attempt to pronounce the "t" at the end or it's because I didn't notice the "t" without sound.

Comment: @LLS: just for clarification, it's 'n zero' or n sub zero' in AmE. (any use of 'nought' sounds very BrE to me)

Comment: @LLS: Do people in Hong Kong pronounce the 't' in *port?* Since Hong Kong has a British-derived non-rhotic accent, *port* should rhyme with *nought.*

Comment: @Peter Shor: At least I can feel a 't' there. I think they do. "Port" doesn't sound strange to me. There are some commonly used words whose pronunciation is somewhat different from standard English.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you were reading it out to somebody, eg. to write down in a lecture, I would say N-sub-zero.
But if this is a particular mathematical term then it's probably N-nought, or N-null. Sometimes the term has a particular usage from history or convention (eg the original paper or a famous textbook) whatever the rules of regular English grammar might say.

eg. the set of cardinal numbers [image: aleph-null] is normally Aleph-nought or Aleph-null

Comment: Pronounced Aleph-null only if your teacher was German.  (Or his teacher, and so on...)  Otherwise pronounced nought or zero just like other subscripts.

Comment: Or because it was invented by Georg Cantor

Comment: OK, I suppose Cantor would have said "Aleph-eins" but we don't do that in English.

Comment: I read about this in a book (probably Kasner & Newman's _Mathematic and the imagination_) long before I went to college, and have always called it _aleph-null_.

Comment: Yeah, my Physics teacher says "nought."

Answer (score 12):

From a native US English speaker:

As there don't seem to be any readily available pronunciation guidance resources on this subject, I am forced to be subjective.  I believe "zero" is the most common, in the US, at least.  Since I do not prefer to call `"0"` anything other than "zero" in any situation, I would say:

> N-zero *for nₒ*
>
> N-two *for n₂*
>
> Etc.

As to your last question, I confess I wouldn't understand someone who said "N-nor", without further enlightenment.

Comment: In the US, we also say "N-nought".

Comment: Yes.  I have heard both "nought" and "zero" used on both sides of the Atlantic, but I think "zero" is [more common](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=zero%2Cnought&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) on either side, in any usage.  And if one calls `0` _zero_, one tends to call `nₒ` "N-zero".  At least, so I infer.

Comment: @Peter: Some in the US might use 'nought', but it is pretty rare.

Comment: In my US college math courses, my prof read it as "N-sub-aught."

Comment: I guess there are some differences in different areas. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Here in Canada we use 'N-nought'. I have NEVER heard N-zero or N-nor. This is solely from my experience, having taken many math courses in university.

Answer (score 1):

*Aught* is another word for "zero". So when you have y<sub>0</sub>, you would say "y aught".

Comment: A wee archaic, no? The accepted answer suggests _naught_ / _nought_.

Comment: I've not heard "aught" used like that on either side of the Atlantic. Definitely poetic/archaic to use "aught" to mean zero. The current use seems to be only of "aughts" plural meaning the ten year period from 2000 through 2009.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely pronounced 'naught' (sounds almost like "not"... or the beginning of "naughty" without the "ty" on the end).  At least this is true for American Engineering, Physics, and Mathematics.  Naught, as a living word, is more British than American, however, and rarely would an American ever be heard saying the word naught (outside of a mathematics-based class).  Why "n-naught" instead of "n-nor" or "n-zero"...  I imagine there is a poetic/linguistic reason for holding strong to a pronunciation that is not really used anywhere else... I would say x-naught sounds better than the alternatives.  Or perhaps pronunciation memes are stronger when positioned within a mathematical context than in a quotidian one?  For instance there is little variance in how we pronounce words such as "sine" "π" or "logarithm".  The first few numbers have accents, but that's likely because they are everyday words... and not intently focused upon by very serious individuals.

Answer (score 1):

In American English, N<sub>0</sub> is usually pronounced "N-naught" or "N-sub-zero," with "sub" short for "subscript." In any of my math or physics classes, I've never heard it pronounced "N-nor" or "N-zero" as many people are saying here.

Answer (score 0):

My physics, chemistry and mathematics teachers used to call it **n-suffix-zero** sometimes, but mostly just **n-zero** or **n-naught.**

I studied in private English-medium Indian schools, in the Middle East.

Answer (score -4):

I’m in America and have never heard any of those; my teacher says “N-Oh” as in the letter.

Comment: But nₒ is very different from n₀, even if it does look similar.

Comment: Yeah, but Americans are notorious for saying “oh” when they mean “zero”.